# Parar o Parsing automático do Vs Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Galera, no meu vs code, quando fico um tempo inativo (sem estar na aba )

Ele começa um parsing automático dos arquivos.

```
Parsing file:///var/www/html/jvt.org.br/wp-content/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/vendor/Aws3/Aws/data/ecs/2014-11-13/waiters-2.json.php
```

Ele abre o output automaticamente e faz o mostrado acima.

Como tirar essa configuração? Já procurei web a fora e não encontrei nada a respeito.

Comment: Já viu isso: https://github.com/felixfbecker/php-language-server/issues/311

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a resposta no stack em inglês

Turn off PHP validation: settings.json

> // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
>   {
>   "php.validate.enable": false
>   }
>   Use comma separators to overwrite multiple default settings: settings.json.
>
> // Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
>   {
>   "php.validate.enable": false,
>   "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
>   "editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
>   "editor.wordWrap": true
>   }

Depois de adicionado essas configurações o vs code para de abrir automaticamente o output para fazer parsing dos arquivos.